# On Cascade Deletion not working in slave server when using Postgres' Publication/subscription

Tags: postgresql

I am using Postgres' Publication/Subscription to keep two tables in different databases synchronized. Table A in the master database is in tandem with table A in the slave database. The solution is working reasonably well.

The problem arises in deletion a record. When a record is deleted from the master table, all the child records are also removed in the master database. However, although the deletion is correctly propagated in the slave server for table A, the child records are not deleted.

Is not this the expected behavior? What am I missing?

The Publication/Subscription were created like this:

```
CREATE PUBLICATION pub FOR TABLE  A;

CREATE SUBSCRIPTION sub
CONNECTION 'host=localhost dbname=xxx user=postgres password=password'
PUBLICATION pub
WITH (create_slot = false, slot_name='slot_name', copy_data=false);
```